# Using awk to increment specific characters

Tags: unix, awk, numbers, increment

I have a file where field 11 contains the following string

```
FP6000
```

And i need to increment the final 4 digits +1 each time and overwrite contents of the script with the new number

So increment to FP6001

I've used the following in the past which worked fine but these were all digits no letters

```
awk '{$11=$11+1}1' $FILE > tmp && mv tmp $FILE
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Use any version `awk` like this:

```sh
s='FP6000'
awk '{f=$1; sub(/[0-9]+$/, "", f); sub(/^[^0-9]*/, "", $1); print f ($1+1)}' <<< "$s"

FP6001
```

We store `$1` in variable `f` then remove all digits in the end. From `$1` we strip out all non-digits from start and then append `f` and `$1+1` together for printing.

Comment: This is great thanks, how can i then use this value to replace string 11 from my original file?

Comment: If you show your complete input with expected output then I can look into that. Remember your original problem is to increment a number which is part of a alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 1):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
1 2 3 4 5 66 7 8 9 10 FP6000 12 13
```

With GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
$ awk '{split($11,lets,/[0-9]+$/,digs); $11=lets[1] digs[1]+1} 1' file
1 2 3 4 5 66 7 8 9 10 FP6001 12 13
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($11,/[0-9]/){$11=substr($11,1,RSTART-1) substr($11,RSTART)+1} 1' file
1 2 3 4 5 66 7 8 9 10 FP6001 12 13
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print just `$11+1` you will get `1` as "FP6000" is a string evaluating to 0 when you add 1 to it.

---

A variation using `gnu awk` using a regex with 2 capture groups, setting field 11 to the first group which matches all till before the last digits, followed by an incremented value for group 2

```
(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]+)$
```

- `(.*[^0-9])?` Optional capture group 1, matching all until the last occurrence of a non digit
- `([0-9]+)` Capture group 2, match 1 or more digits
- `$` End of string

As the first group is optional, it will also work if there are only digits.

```
awk 'match($11,/(.*[^0-9])?([0-9]+)$/,a) {$11=a[1](++a[2])}1' $FILE > tmp && mv tmp $FILE
```

Input

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 FP6000 a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 6000 a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1A2BFP6000 a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 FP6000X a b c
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 FP6001 a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 6001 a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 1A2BFP6001 a b c
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 FP6000X a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perl to do that:

```
perl -lnE 'say $1.($2+1) if m/^([^\d]+)(\d+)/' file
FP6001
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, another GNU `awk` solution:

```
awk '{l=gensub(/[0-9]+$/, "", 1); num=gensub(/^[^0-9]+/, "", 1); print l (num + 1)}' file
```

I.e., `l` is the word, `num` is the number. Once obtained, increment the `num` and print them.